# Is there a division algebra of characteristic 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras

**Question**

I need a division algebra D of characteristic 2, of 4 dimensional over its center Z(D), with an element $x\not \in Z(D), x^2\in Z(D)$. Is there any such D?

**What I know**

The quaternion algebra does not work in a field of characteristic 2. And I know that any finite division rings are fields.

Comment: For the quaternion algebra in characteristic $2$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199103/quaternion-algebra-of-characteristic-2), for example.

Comment: That is a field. But I need an x not in the center as in the question.

Comment: You write "the quaternion algebra does not work in a field of characteristic $2$". That's because you are not using the best definition. Don't define quaternion algebras by *explicit formulas*, but rather by *concepts*: a quaternion algebra over a field $K$ should be a 4-dimensional central simple algebra over $K$. These exist over many fields in all characteristics, including characteristic $2$.  If you try to write them down with *formulas* they look different, but the description I just gave works over all fields (the "unified definition" that Captain Lama refers to in the answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quaternion algebras do work in characteristic $2$, they are just a little different (though it is possible to give a unified definition). Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $2$, and let $a\in K$ and $b\in K^\times$.

Then you can define a $K$-algebra $Q$ with generators $i$ and $j$ satisfying
$$i^2+i=a,\quad j^2=b,\quad ij = j(i+1).$$

The algebra $Q$ is central simple over $K$, of dimension $4$ (with basis $1,i,j,ij$). And you see that $j^2$ is in the center. Also, $Q$ is usually a division algebra, unless $b$ is a norm for $K(i)/K$.

Where does this definition come from? Over a field of characteristic $2$, there are $2$ types of quadratic extensions: separable ones, and inseparable ones. The inseparable quadratic extensions $L/K$ have the familiar form $L\simeq K(\sqrt{b})$ for some $b\in K^\times$. But the separable ones look like $L\simeq K(\wp^{-1}(a))$ for some $a\in K$, where $\wp: K\to K$ is the function $\wp(x)=x^2+x$.

Then in the definition of $Q$, we see the two types of quadratic extensions: $K(j)\simeq K(\sqrt{b})$ is inseparable, and $K(i)\simeq K(\wp^{-1}(a))$ is separable. Note that $K(i)/K$ is a Galois extension, and the conjugation by $j$ in $Q$ induces the non-trivial automorphism of $K(i)/K$, ie $i\mapsto i+1$.

Comment: Your idea is right. But the choice of K,a,b is not easy.

Comment: It's not really that hard either: for instance take $K=\mathbb{F}_2(X,Y)$, $a=X$ and $b=Y$.